# Need Help Hiding Sidebar on Custom Wordpress Php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using the underscores theme to build my wordpress site. It is very barebones (which I like), but they didn't seem to include a page.php and post.php file, instead they just have page. This means if I have a sidebar, it shows on all pages and posts. The code to show the sidebar is

```
<?php if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )) {
    return;
}
?>
```

I've tried a number of if statements to exclude pages but I can't seem to get it right. How would I have it so if the person is on a page it doesn't return the sidebar?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the page.php and REMOVE the sidebar:

`<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>`

or the get_sidebar() function.

```
get_sidebar();
```

Comment: This worked!! On my pages I don't have the sidebar anymore. The one thing I don't understand is how it works if I don't have a post.php file.

Comment: Wordpress uses Template Hierarchy. WordPress searches down through the template hierarchy until it finds a matching template file. To determine which template file to use. 

Also, the The post file is the single.php in your theme/child theme folder. If the single.php is not present it will use the page.php. Go ahead try creating the single.php and copy the content from page.php and edit some stuff in single.php and check your post page. :)

You may want to read about WP Template Hierarchy here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/